# Oracle Start With In Limit

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

In a complex query, if I enter a small number of records in the startwith, the result returns quickly, but when I manually fill in around 180 records in "in", it seems as if it is locked and the result is not returned for hours.

```
SELECT * FROM ORGANIZATION 
START WITH ID IN (150002755,150002757,....) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENTID
```

If I delete the record that I filled manually and pull the same data from a table, the result is accelerated again. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You'll have to show you table and index structure, describe the data and show the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) for *both* queries.

Comment: Also your expected output?